# Run grep (like this)

Tags: grep

I use the standard `grep` command a lot. When I execute it, the minibuffer is populated with the following the text, allowing me to complete the command:

```
Run grep (like this): grep --color -nH --null -e
```

I almost always prefer to use Perl regex and ignore casing, so I'm finding myself replacing the last argument very often like so:

```
Run grep (like this): grep --color -nH --null -Pi
```

I would like to change the behavior of `grep` so that it loads with the argument `-Pi` instead of `-e` by default.

When I use `describe-function` and inspect `grep`, I can see the lines (in `/usr/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/progmodes/grep.el.gz`) that define this behavior. Beginning line 650, there is a codeblock like so:

```
      (let ((grep-options
         (concat (if grep-use-null-device "-n" "-nH")
                     (if grep-use-null-filename-separator " --null")
             (if (grep-probe grep-program
                     `(nil nil nil "-e" "foo" ,null-device)
                     nil 1)
             " -e"))))
       (...
```

How do I override these `grep-options` in my Emacs config? I cannot find a variable named `grep-probe` or `grep-options` which I could just overwrite, for example, so what's the best practice then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The needed variable to set is called `grep-command`, resulting in `(setq grep-command "grep --color -nH --null -Pi")`